# How do I achieve pixel perfect alignment of all styles attached to this select element?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<select>` element that I am trying to style as much as I can using CSS only. I've managed to take it pretty far, and [you can see a test example with garish colours for clarity on JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/2a3h7tea/).

When the page first loads, the pseudo-button with the down arrow is misaligned with the top of the `<select>` element by 1 pixel (at least in Chrome, where I am testing):

[image: pseudo-button off by one pixel on top]

Then, after you click the `<select>` element, the top aligns, but there is an extra one pixel of white space on the bottom, below the pseudo-button (it does not matter if you select a different option or not):

[image: extra white space below pseudo-button after click]

**How can I correct these alignment problems so that the white and blue areas have pixel perfect alignment, before and after the `<select>` element is clicked?**

I have tried a variety of CSS to try and kill focus and borders.

```css
body {
  background-color: #999;
}
.select {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 12em;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: .25em;
}
select {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 .5em;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-width: 0;
    border-style: none;
    outline: none;
    outline-style:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    border-color:transparent;
    resize: none;
}
select:focus {
    outline: none;
    outline-style:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    border-color:transparent;
    resize: none;
}
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
/* Arrow */
.select::after {
    content: '\25BC';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0 1em;
    background: blue;
    pointer-events: none;
}
/* Transition */
.select:hover::after {
    color: red;
}
.select::after {
    -webkit-transition: .25s all ease;
    -o-transition: .25s all ease;
    transition: .25s all ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="select">
  <select id="languageSelector">
    <option>English</option>
    <option>French</option>
    <option>Chinese</option>
    <option>Japanese</option>
    <option>Russian</option>
    <option>Spanish</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

Remove `line-height` property from `.select` and paste it in `.select::after`

CSS

```
.select::after{
line-height: 3em;
}
```

Hope this Helps

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting `line-height` on the `.select` class set it on the pseudo element itself.

```
.select::after {
  line-height: 3em;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}

.select {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 12em;
    height: 3em;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: .25em;
}
select {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 .5em;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-width: 0;
    border-style: none;
    outline: none;
    outline-style:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    border-color:transparent;
    resize: none;
}
select:focus {
    outline: none;
    outline-style:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    border-color:transparent;
    resize: none;
}
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
/* Arrow */
.select::after {
    content: '\25BC';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0 1em;
    line-height: 3em;
    background: blue;
    pointer-events: none;
}
/* Transition */
.select:hover::after {
    color: red;
}
.select::after {
    -webkit-transition: .25s all ease;
    -o-transition: .25s all ease;
    transition: .25s all ease;
}
```

```html
                    <div class="select">
                        <select id="languageSelector">
                            <option>English</option>
                            <option>French</option>
                            <option>Chinese</option>
                            <option>Japanese</option>
                            <option>Russian</option>
                            <option>Spanish</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to how the browser calculates `height: 100%;` (based on `line-height`).  You can achieve it to be pixel perfect by specifying the height in pixels.

```css
body {
  background-color: #999;
}
.select {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 12em;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: .25em;
}
select {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 .5em;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-width: 0;
    border-style: none;
    outline: none;
    outline-style:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    border-color:transparent;
    resize: none;
}
select:focus {
    outline: none;
    outline-style:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    border-color:transparent;
    resize: none;
}
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
/* Arrow */
.select::after {
    content: '\25BC';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0 1em;
    background: blue;
    pointer-events: none;
}
/* Transition */
.select:hover::after {
    color: red;
}
.select::after {
    -webkit-transition: .25s all ease;
    -o-transition: .25s all ease;
    transition: .25s all ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="select">
  <select id="languageSelector">
    <option>English</option>
    <option>French</option>
    <option>Chinese</option>
    <option>Japanese</option>
    <option>Russian</option>
    <option>Spanish</option>
  </select>
</div>
```